# Parent PySide widget to Application

Tags: python, pyside

Is it possible to parent a pyside widget/dialog/mainwindow to any application for example the current running instance of Notepad?

As a result the PySide dialog would always stay on top of the widget and minimize when the parent application minimizes and so forth?

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Icon')
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('web.png'))        

        self.show()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This method is commonly found in many modern applications, giving studios the additional ability of extending functionalities with pyside tools running inside the application.

Here are some:

- The Foundry Nuke
- The Foundry Mari
- Autodesk 3ds Max
- Autodesk 3ds Maya
- Blender
- Cinema 4D

Comment: Do you want to embed Notepad to the PySide window?

Comment: no i want notepad to run as it normally would. when i launch my pyside app i would like to have it attach to the running instance of notepad

Comment: What do you mean by *attach* ?, do you want that if you move the PySide window also Notepad moves?

Comment: If so, I recommend you check information about the Windows API. that has nothing to do with Qt.

Comment: Most modern applications now a days support pyside scripting in them. And when you create a pyside tool in these application, you usually have to attached your pyside dialog to the main application so when you close the application or minimize it, your pyside tool closes or minimizes as well.

Comment: You could point to one of those *modern applications*.

Comment: updated to show a list of some applications